# parse error in if statement: missing required else clause in Haskell code

Tags: parsing, if-statement, haskell, haskell-platform

I am receiving "parse error in if statement: missing required else clause" on line 202. I believe I am using the correct if-then-else syntax for haskell. But let me know what's wrong. Thanks

I've tried shifting the various if statements around but to no avail

```hs
playerMove p e =
 if ((getPHealth p) > 0) then
  do 
     putStrLn (showOpts2)
     move <- getLine
     if (move == 0) then
      do 
        let e = Enemy (getEDescription e) ((getEHealth e) - (getPAttack p)) (getEAttack e)
        putStrLn ("you dealt " + (getPAttack p) + " damage to your foe")
        enemyMove p e
     if (move == 1) then
      do 
        let p = Player (getPHealth) (getPAttack) (getPScore) True
        return p
        else return p
     else return p
 else return p
```

Comment: Like the error says, you're missing an `else`. It should be before `if (move == 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

It's this bit:

```
if (move == 0) then
 do 
   let e = Enemy (getEDescription e) ((getEHealth e) - (getPAttack p)) (getEAttack e)
   putStrLn ("you dealt " + (getPAttack p) + " damage to your foe")
   enemyMove p e
-- No else here before indentation is reduced
if (move == 1) then
```

There are a couple other things I notice here. Check the type of `move`; does `move == 0` make sense? Instead of horrendously nested `if/then/else`, Haskell provides a nice `switch`-like construct, detailed at the bottom of [this Learn You a Haskell page](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions).

Answer (score 0):

I shifted the innermost `if` statement forward, and it seems to compile. I don't know if this keeps the original intent of the program.

Also, `getLine` returns a string, but you are comparing the output to an `Int`. And `++` is string concatenation, not `+`.

I hope this helps. Good luck!

```
playerMove p e =
 if ((getPHealth p) > 0) then
  do
     putStrLn (showOpts2)
     move <- getLine
     if (move == "0") then
      do 
        let e = Enemy (getEDescription e) ((getEHealth e) - (getPAttack p)) (getEAttack e)
        putStrLn ("you dealt " ++ (getPAttack p) ++ " damage to your foe")
        enemyMove p e
        if (move == "1") then
          do 
            let p = Player (getPHealth) (getPAttack) (getPScore) True
            return p
        else return p
     else return p
 else return p
```

Comment: It probably doesn't keep the original intent, now that I actually read it I see that move can't equal "0" and "1".

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

### Using a "case of" construct instead of an "if then else" one:

As mentioned by Khuldraeseth na'Barya, you could use a `case of` construct. This would allow the extra case of move being neither 0 nor 1 to fit nicely.

It is a bit difficult to *fill in the blanks* as we haven't seen your types, but this code compiles, under reasonable assumptions for the object types:

```
playerMove :: Move -> Move -> IO Move
playerMove p e =
  if ((getPHealth p) > 0) then
    do 
      putStrLn (showOpts2)
      moveStr <- getLine
      let move = (read moveStr)::Integer
      case move of
        0 -> do 
               let e = Enemy (getEDescription e) ((getEHealth e) - (getPAttack p)) (getEAttack e)
               putStrLn $ ("you dealt " ++ (show (getPAttack p)) ++ " damage to your foe")
               enemyMove p e
        1 -> do
               let p = Player (getPHealth) (getPAttack) (getPScore) True
               return p
        _ -> do
               return p -- what if move is neither 0 nor 1 ??
  else
    return p
```